# Decimal point or decimal comma in Android

Tags: android, decimal-point

Is there an easy way to read back if the language set uses a decimal comma or a decimal point?

Comment: Your current "selected answer" is that of a user who stole someone else's answer in this very thread and just copy pasted into his post. I encourage you to rectify this so that such malicious behavior is not rewarded on Stackoverflow. Here is the original answer which was stolen from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52581208/2057171

Answer (score 35, accepted):

EDIT: Updating based on @Algar's suggestion; you can directly use:

```
char separatorChar = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator();
```

As it will always return an instance  of `DecimalFormatSymbols`.

---

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
if (nf instanceof DecimalFormat) {
    DecimalFormatSymbols sym = ((DecimalFormat) nf).getDecimalFormatSymbols();
    char decSeparator = sym.getDecimalSeparator();
}
```

Docs:

[`NumberFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html), [`DecimalFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html)

According to the DecimalFormat docs, apparently calling NumberFormat.getInstance() is safe, but may return a subclass other than DecimalFormat (the other option I see is ChoiceFormat). I believe for the majority of instances it should be a DecimalFormat, and then you can compare `decSeparator` against a `,` and `.` to see which format it is using.

Comment: I needed to cast `nf` to `DecimalFormat` `((DecimalFormat)nf).getDecimalFormatSymbols()`, thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks @SelçukCihan, I've edited the answer to include the required cast!

Comment: @kcoppock No you didn't :)

Comment: @rozina Heh, how about now? :)

Answer (score 7):

Or why not

```
DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().decimalSeparator
```

Comment: Good idea! I've incorporated this into the accepted answer above.

Comment: @KevinCoppock Don't you think it's kind of weird to take someone else's answer, which is better than yours, and then just copy paste it into your main answer, so that you get the upvotes, not the answerer?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw It's a classic duche move for sure :)

Answer (score 2):

I did try this and it worked fine...

```
    String osVersion = System.getProperty("os.version");
String PhoneModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
String locale = this.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayCountry();
char decSeparator = '*';
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
decSeparator = dfs.getDecimalSeparator();
String androidVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
String prologue = String.format("OS verson = %s PhoneModel = %s locale = %s DecimalFormatSymbol = [%c] androidVersion = %s ", 
        osVersion ,PhoneModel, locale, decSeparator,androidVersion);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(device_locale);
```

than use `currency.getSymbol()` for symbol. For default device locale you can use:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public static Locale getCurrentLocale(Context c) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return c.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
        } else {
            //noinspection deprecation
            return c.getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if there is an easy way, but you could test which language set is being used and then make the appropriate changes according to if that language used commas or decimals.

Comment: language and decimal separator are two different problem. in add, you are unlikly to list all the existing language.