# Wrong decimal separator returned by DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().decimalSeparator

Tags: android, kotlin, decimal-point

Based on this question: [Decimal point or decimal comma in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188137/decimal-point-or-decimal-comma-in-android) I try to get decimal separator used in the device. I am using Kotlin so my code looks like this:

```
import android.icu.text.DecimalFormatSymbols

DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().decimalSeparator  // function used in onCreate()
```

This code returns **`,`** but on the device, the separator used e.g. in EditText is **`.`**. Why does this happen?

---

An example where I think it returns the wrong result:

```
import android.icu.text.DecimalFormatSymbols

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        txtSeparator.text = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().decimalSeparator.toString()
        txtTest.text = (1234.5678).toString()
    }
}
```

[image]

Why separator in first TextView is different than in the second TextView or in the EditText? It happens in some langueages. In English it works but e.g. in Polish doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The line `txtTest.text = (1234.5678).toString()` is just telling the VM that it should use the standard number-to-string conversion proccess, so it will put a dot as a decimal separator and, if you use a double with more decimal places, it will even use scientific notation. You should, instead, have a look at this page from Android Developers, where there are specific methods to work with number formatting: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat

Comment: But why in EditText I have to use `.` instead of `,` when default separator in device is set to `,`?

Comment: I don't know what code you're using to parse the value from the `EditText`, so it's hard to predict the behavior.

Comment: I am not using any code. It is normal `EditText` with type `numberDecimal`. I click on it, keyboard shows and I can only add `.` as a separator.

Comment: In that case, try this https://gist.github.com/juniorcesarabreu/4324e43b6046f5ddcde80389c66eb90f